# How can find "<< >>" words from string

Tags: php, regex

I have tried some regex pattern but still can not find some solution for this.

I want get `<< >>` words from following string.

```
$string = "Yes! Bariatric surgery is covered under your plan. Click <<COMPANY>> here to contact a local surgeon and ask them to confirm your insurance benefits for free. See our <<INSURANCE>> page for coverage criteria or scroll down this page to learn more."; 
$dash = substr($string,strpos($string,"<<"),strpos($string,">>"));
```

If any one knows please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, where is your code, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: Please update your question with your code and explain that what's wrong with output?

Comment: I have find my solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will match the words between `<<` and `>>`

```
\<{2}([^\>]+)\>{2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/eX4xI4/1

```
preg_match_all("/\<{2}([^\>]+)\>{2}/", $string, $matches);
print_r( $matches );
```

https://eval.in/602428

Comment: Thanks Buddy it's work......

Comment: No sweat  `:)`  Glad i could help

Comment: If it works you should accept the answer. The `<` and `>` don't need to be escaped; `<{2}([^>]+)>{2}`.